# AWS Boto3 - Datapoint within client.get_metric_statistics displays on one file but not on the other

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I have this function that records a Cloudwatch metric called `client.get_metric_statistics`, when I execute it the Datapoint doesn't show but I extracted the metric function to another file by itself and when executed it displayed the datapoint with no issues.

The only thing different is that I had a InstanceId on the one that displayed fine and I had a AMIID as you see on my main script which has to be automated so I am not sure if AMIID is allowed to be used but I dont see why it shouldnt or what the issue is so i'm looking for some feedback.

```py
import sys
import boto3
import time
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='eu-west-1')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')


instance = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId='ami-02ifd1b532b22l6h3',
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    InstanceType='t2.nano',
    KeyName = 'key1.pem',
    SecurityGroupIds=[sg.group_id],
    UserData = user_data,
)
```

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time.sleep(300)
client = boto3.client("cloudwatch")
response = client.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace="AWS/EC2",
    MetricName="CPUUtilization",
    Dimensions=[{"Name": "AMIID", "Value": "ami-13add1h575a25e4d6"}],
    StartTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(seconds=200),
    EndTime=datetime.utcnow(),
    Period=300,
    Statistics=["Average"],
    Unit="Percent",
)
print(response)

for cpu in response["Datapoints"]:
    print(cpu)
```

```
s3.Bucket(name='buket2')
ec2.SecurityGroup(id='sg-06b84927ae5rd3ad1')
{'Label': 'CPUUtilization', 'Datapoints': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '357', 'date': 'Sun, 18 Jul 2021 00:26:57 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
sg-06b84927ae5rd3ad1
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Amazon EC2 metric dimensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html#ec2-cloudwatch-dimensions):

> **ImageId:** This dimension filters the data you request for all instances running this Amazon EC2 Amazon Machine Image (AMI). Available for instances with Detailed Monitoring enabled.

You appear to be using `AMIID` instead of `ImageId`.

You can always view available dimensions using:

```
aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace 'AWS/EC2'
```

Comment: Also I notice if I launch more than 1 instance it doesn't display for each, is there any way to make this possible?

Comment: You would need to provide the Dimension that refers to a specific instance. Otherwise, all metrics are combined. For example, Auto Scaling Groups have Scaling Policies that react to the **Average CPU Utilization of all instances in the Auto Scaling group**. It does this by specifying the Auto Scaling group as a dimension, and then receives back a _combined average_ of all instances matching that dimension. This is the intentional design of Amazon CloudWatch. If you want separate metrics for each instance, then you'll need to query for the dimensions, then get the stats for each instance alone.

Comment: Interesting... Did not know. Will look into it, thanks for the detailed explanation John!

Answer (score 0):

Avaiable dimensions for EC2 are listed in [Amazon EC2 metric dimensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html#ec2-cloudwatch-dimensions). There is **no dimension called AMIID**.

I guess you wanted to use `ImageId` which is **valid** dimension.

Comment: @HmNoon So what happened? Why did you un-accepted the answer?